Orbeon Forms - How to enter Complex CSS Code
I was trying to use the IF/THEN/ELSE syntax in the Custom CSS Classes field within a control
For example, we wanted to change the background colour of a text depending on a radio-button setting:
So

radio-button "HIGH" should set a red background
radio-button "MEDIUM" should set a amber background
radio-button "Low" should set a green background

I tried various code but I cant get it to work.
Any help would be most appreciated
PeteA

Custom CSS Classes support AVTs (Attribute Value Templates), which are XPath expressions enclosed in curly braces. Open the Control Settings for the control you want to style, and in Custom CSS Classes, use expressions like:
my-priority-{//priority}

Assuming you have another control named priority and its value is high, the current control will receive the class my-priority-high. You can then write CSS that sets the background to red when the class my-priority-high is present.

Thanks Alex,
Here's a test form that works:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/fbfa7b5fbcc7f661c93af0c3cb83ae94e337d966

@PeteAtkin Cool, thank you for sharing that example.
